# Don't match negative integers

Tags: regex

[image: regex101]

### Quiz

Could you help me validate my input and only match positive integers between the range of 0 and 100? There can be several numbers in a string which I would want to retrieve. Try out these example strings:

`Sam has 200 apples. He gives Todd 20 and Mary 125. and The weather is -5 C today, but will be +5 C tomorrow.`

I tried `\b(100|\d\d|\d)\b` but unable to get rid of `-5`. How do I solve the question?

Comment: I've reverted your edit to add "solved" to the end of the title of your question. It's not recommended, or necessary, to do that when you accept an answer as there are cues in the GUI that tell others that you've accepted an answer - most obviously the green tick.

Comment: I thought it will be a benefit to the search system, especially when you want to find a solved question. I am not sure a user could easy to find or see a question from a list that is solved.

Comment: I get what you're saying, but what I did is the recommended action here - see, e.g. [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116105/284827) or [this](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/7413/529101). Regarding the search system, there are visual cues in the search results that show questions which have accepted answers, e.g the number of answers (on the left) are shown in a filled green box instead of a white box.

Comment: For example, looking on your profile, [I can see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrneB.jpg) questions with accepted answers vs. without. The "(solved)" on the second answer down is also superfluous. In a search, I can search for questions without accepted answers by using `hasaccepted:false`, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq+hasaccepted%3Afalse). Anyway, this is not directly related to your question. My intention isn't to antagonise you - if you have an issue, please bring it up on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com) - ping me and I'll reply. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. If somebody posts answer on comments, how do I accept it?

Comment: If somebody posted an answer in comments, you could suggest they post an answer. If they refuse you can post an answer yourself (credit the commenter) then accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use lookbehind

```
\b(?<!-)(?:\d{1,2}|100)\b
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/0BRuE8/2/)

Answer (score 2):

You can put negative look behind for hyphen using `(?<!-)` before the regex. Also, I think you can shorten the regex. Try this regex,

```
(?<!-)\b(?:100|\d?\d)\b
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kEnEnq/3)**

Note: This is also the shortest possible regex you need in your quiz.

Comment: @Joseph: I actually copied your existing regex where I think you put by mistake `200` instead of `100`. Check with this and this regex should be shortest among other answers.

Comment: @Joseph: Great to know it worked and is the shortest possible :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
\b(?<![-])([0-9][0-9]?|100)\b
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/xyegcH/6)

Comment: Test 26/26: Don't create backreferences when you don't need them. If you need to group, use (?:regex); it's the same as (regex) but it doesn't create a backreference.

Answer (score 0):

```
\b(?<![-\d])(?:\+?(?:100|\d{1,2}))(?!\d)\b
```

\b: Word boundary, ensuring the number is standalone and not part of a larger number.

(?<![-\d]): Negative lookbehind, ensuring there is no hyphen (-) or other digits preceding the number.

+?: An optional plus sign (+), indicating that the number may or may not start with a plus.

(?:100|\d{1,2}): A non-capturing group matching either 100 or any one or two-digit number (\d{1,2}).

(?!\d): Negative lookahead, ensuring no additional digits follow the number.

\b: Word boundary, ensuring the match ends at the number's end.

Comment: While this code may solve the problem the answer would be a lot better with an explanation on how/why it does.  Remember that your answer is not just for the user that asked the question but also for all the other people that find it.